# Bottom of object with Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm diving into geometry nodes today and I have a problem aligning the bottom of my object to Z=0.

I've learned that to achieve this you have to add a [divide node] and [combine node]. You take the total height, then divide it by 2 and with the combine node you can select just the Z axis. The object bottom should align to Z=0 but somehow it wont and the aligning just looks off. At least it wont take half of the object height.

I've tried it both with a Mesh Primitive and without (so just the normal cube in the viewport). Any idea what I might be missing? I've looked everywhere but sadly cant find anything yet since geometry nodes is still a rather new concept in blender.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to use a Vector Math instead of regular Math for dividing. You can use a single node set to divide by (0, 0, 2) that will output a vector with only a 2 component. Using a scalar Math node will average the input values along each coordinate which you don't want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this node setup: (thanks to Robin)

[image]

Comment: I think your arithmetic is upside-down: https://imgur.com/a/MVInRin

Comment: Everything else, just about :D. It only works with the default cube (or other objects, on creation)  because the origin is halfway up the mesh. Shift the defaut cube in Edit Mode, to see what I mean..

Comment: you are right - i updated my answer, thank you Robin.

Comment: Phew! I just updated that link to try to explain what I meant.. I'm not very good at expressing these things except in jumbly ways :)  I already prematurely +1'd :)

Comment: Thank you that did it.